# How do i copy an image link when someone sends an image in chat

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to figure out how to copy the link of an image the user posts. I was trying to figure out how to do this but i cant find anything that helps me, thats all im looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for this :

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.attachments:
        return

    attachment = message.attachments[0]
    await message.channel.send(attachment.url)
```

Reference :

- [`discord.Attachment`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=attachment#discord.Attachment)
- [`discord.Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=attachment#discord.Message.attachments)
- [`discord.on_message(message)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)